# How to make my character look in the direction of the camera in Unity 3d?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My character has a chinemachine camera attached to it and it is moving perfectly fine. But when I move my mouse to change the camera direction it is not looking in that direction. And I can't figure out how to make it look in that direction.

I have a reference to the original camera at the top of the script by the name cam.

The script has different functions for movement, rotation, animation, etc.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

//so that unity recognises the callbacks ctx passed to the movementinput
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class AnimationAndMovController : MonoBehaviour
{
public Transform cam;

public float speed;
//here we are creadting three vars for the animation
//vector2 currentMovementInput stores the input axis of the player
//vector3 store the current position of the player


PlayerInput playerInput; 
CharacterController characterController;
Animator animator;

Vector2 currentMovementInput;
Vector3 currentMovement;
Vector3 currentRunMovement;
Vector3 moveDir;


bool isMovementPressed;
bool isRunPressed;

float rotationFactor = 15.0f;
// float turnSmoothtime = 0.1f;
// float turnSmoothVelocity ;
float runMultiplier = 4.0f;

int walkHash ;
int runHash ;

//runs before start function
void Awake(){
    playerInput = new PlayerInput();
    characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    // walkHash = Animator.StringToHash("Walking");
    // runHash = Animator.StringToHash("run");

    //now instead of writing the logic three times we pass the callback ctx to the movementInput() function
    playerInput.CharacterControls.Move.started += movementInput;
    playerInput.CharacterControls.Move.canceled += movementInput;
    playerInput.CharacterControls.Move.performed += movementInput;
    playerInput.CharacterControls.Run.started += handleRun;
    playerInput.CharacterControls.Run.canceled += handleRun;
}

void handleRun(InputAction.CallbackContext ctx){
    isRunPressed = ctx.ReadValueAsButton();
}

//we are going to handle rotations with quaternions
void handleRotation(){
    Vector3 positionToLookAt;

    positionToLookAt.x = currentMovement.x;
    positionToLookAt.y = 0.0f ;
    positionToLookAt.z = currentMovement.z;

    Vector3 direction = new Vector3(positionToLookAt.x, 0.0f, positionToLookAt.z).normalized;

    Quaternion currentRotation = transform.rotation;

    //we take the current rotation and the target rotation and slerp them *FYI : Im still not sure how slerp works
    if(isMovementPressed){
        Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(positionToLookAt);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(currentRotation, targetRotation, rotationFactor * Time.deltaTime);

        
    }

}

//we are passing the callback ctx to this function so that we dont have to call the function everytime we start, cancel or perform the movement
void movementInput(InputAction.CallbackContext ctx){
    //we are setting the movement input to the axis of the player
    currentMovementInput = ctx.ReadValue<Vector2>();
    currentMovement.x = currentMovementInput.x;
    //we are setting the z axis to the y axis of the player because we move y axis on keyboard or joystick but in game we move in z axis
    currentMovement.z = currentMovementInput.y;


    //now we are setting the run movement to the current movement
    currentRunMovement.x = currentMovementInput.x *  runMultiplier;
    currentRunMovement.z = currentMovementInput.y * runMultiplier;

    isMovementPressed = currentMovementInput.x != 0 || currentMovementInput.y != 0;

}

void handleAnimation(){
    bool walk = animator.GetBool("walking");
    bool run = animator.GetBool("run");

    if(isMovementPressed && !walk){
        animator.SetBool("walking", true);
    }
    else if(!isMovementPressed && walk){
        animator.SetBool("walking", false);
    }

    if((isMovementPressed && isRunPressed) && !run){
        animator.SetBool("run", true);
    }
    else if((!isMovementPressed || !isRunPressed)&& run){
        animator.SetBool("run", false);
    }
}

void handleGravity(){
    //we are setting the gravity to -9.8f because we are moving in y axis
    if(characterController.isGrounded){
        float groundGravity = -0.05f;
        currentMovement.y = groundGravity;
        currentRunMovement.y = groundGravity;

    }
    else{
        float gravity = -9.8f;
        currentMovement.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        currentRunMovement.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    handleAnimation();
    handleRotation();
    handleGravity();
    
    if(isRunPressed){
        characterController.Move(currentRunMovement * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    else{
        

     characterController.Move(currentMovement * Time.deltaTime);
    }
   
}

//we are checking if the player script gets enabled or disabled and accordingly we are enabling or disabling the player input
void OnEnable(){
    playerInput.CharacterControls.Enable();
}

void OnDisable(){
    playerInput.CharacterControls.Disable();
}
```

}

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now. Your code is in `c#`

Answer (score 1):

That quite a lot of code to dive into.
I'd try:

```
Quaternion cameraRot = Camera.Main.transform.rotation;
transform.rotation = cameraRot;
```

Or if you have a target [Quaternion.LookRotation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html):

```
Vector3 relativePos = target.position - transform.position;

// the second argument, upwards, defaults to Vector3.up
Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(relativePos, Vector3.up);
transform.rotation = rotation;
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

Use [Transform.LookAt](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html), which points a Game Object's rotation towards a target's position.

In your case, this would be

```
transform.LookAt(cam);
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the code that I use..

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveCamera : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float sensitivity = 1000f;
    public float xRotation = 0f;
    

    public Transform playerBody;
    public Quaternion localRotate;
    
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float MX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X")*sensitivity*Time.deltaTime;
        float MY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y")*sensitivity*Time.deltaTime;

        xRotation -= MY;
        xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation,-90f,90f);
        
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation,0f,0f);
        localRotate = transform.localRotation;
        playerBody.Rotate(Vector3.up * MX);
    }
}
```

the player body you see is the player object to you character...
note that the camera is use  is not In. cinema chine and is inside of the player...